# Using methods/code from parent class Java Inheritance , duplicate member variables conflict?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

**Update**: I am basically posting data from this Object to a REST API endpoint, but my real question here is dealing with Object orientated programming, inheritance here. Sorry if my example isn't the best.

I have parent class, call it **Mustang**, and then a child class, call it **MustangGT**. My real code is slightly different, but I will generalize here for simplicity. I am trying to reuse some methods/code from the parent class since the child class is almost identical, except it has different member variables (instance variables), so I don't duplicate unnecessary code (DRY principle). My issue is that when I try to call `super.buildHttpRequest` (the parent class method I want to use), it is using the wrong member (instance) variables in that method (from the parent class) instead of my child class. My code structure looks like this:

```
public class Mustang {
    String brand = "Ford";
    String model = "Mustang";
    String engineType = "V6";
    int year = 2015;
    double price = 19999.00;

    public Observable<HttpResponseData> buildHttpRequest() {
    // Build up Car object here; I have WAY more complex, tedious objects with way more parameters in my 
    // real code, hence why I don't want to repeat

    Car car = new Car(brand, model, engineType, year, price);

    // Imagine here I make a Http POST request to some endpoint, passing the above created object above as arg

    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> SomeHttpClientLibarary.httpPost(url, car));
}
```

... so in my child class, its very similiar so I want to reuse that `buildHttpRequest()` method, but I want to use it with the member variable data in my child class, ***NOT*** the object that is created and passed in the parent class (the **Car** object)

```
public class MustangGT extendsd Mustang {
    String brand = "Ford";
    String model = "Mustang-GT";
    String engineType = "V12";
    int year = 2019;
    double price = 39999.00;

    @Override
    public Observable<HttpResponseData> buildHttpRequest() {
    return super.buildHttpRequest()
}
```

So you can see how probably my problem. The `super.buildHttpRequest()` call references the parent class method, which is great, but then it uses the member variables like "Mustang" and "V6" instead of my member variables defined in the child class (i.e. "MustangGT" and "V12").

I also have alot more objects created in the class in reality (I simplified for this example) so I *REALLY* don't want to have to re-write that code. Is there something I'm missing here? I guess my OOP skills aren't that great. Do I have refactor something here in order to get this to work the way I want? I know method overriding in Java is supposed to be Runtime polymorphic, and by definition a "Virtual method", but I"m not sure if that helps me here.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I've never seen a car make an HTTP request before. Well, at least not a Mustang. Why would a car have such functionality?

Comment: Lol, I used the "Car" to just represent an object. The general Idea is that I am posting this object data via HTTP to an endpoint. But I want to reuse the method in the parent class. But with the way the parent class method is setup, it uses the wrong object data ( i want to use the data from my child class). That's the issue at hand. I didn't know if there was an Easy "OOP" way to do this; or if I have to refactor the code ; i.e. extract the object instantiation for "Car" outside of the buildHttpRequest method

Comment: I applaud your wanting to apply the DRY principle - but in that respect I cannot understand why you want to repeat the instance variables and methods.   The super class’ brand/model/etc are implicitly available to the subclass (unless they are private, in which case getters can be added), and the super’s buildHttpRequest is also implicitly invoked without the child having to implement anything itself.  So the sub-Class should only add what is not already available in the super class.

Comment: There is something wrong with the types as well. Here Mustang and MustangGT are specific types within a supertype, e.g. MustangType. But maybe that MustangType needs a field that accepts objects of type MustangProperties or similar that can be encoded separately.

Comment: Further, I note that the model and engine type differ between the super and sub - but this would be better handled by each sub-type’s constructor setting the super’s instance variables as desired, rather than declaring new variables at each inheritance level.